# Send automated mail using Infopath 2010 from SharePoint 2010?

Tags: infopath

I have designed an infopath form and deployed as a document template on a SharePoint document library. Now, it has to send an automated email whenever Field value(selected/unselected) changes. Is there a simple way to do it on Infopath itself instead of going with Workflow, Listeners.

Answer (score 1):

In InfoPath Designer, under the 'Data' tab you will need to create a 'data connection' for the email itself.  Then you have to choose how it is launched.  Typically I just do it from 'Form Submit' in the Rules section on the 'Data' tab.  *** Keep in mind, this will send an email every time the form is saved, not when the field changes.  In fact, if they change nothing at all and hit save, it will still send the email.

That is the simplest way.  If you want to have it generated by a specific field change, it will require a bit more logic.